# Partial maven release

Tags: java, git, maven, svn, release-management

I'd like to hear your oppinion, how to resolve our release management.

CURRENT STATE

We are using SVN, Maven. We have some shared libraries, some shared EJBs and multiple .war projects for processing various messages. All those projects are in one SVN repo.

THE PROBLEM

When we are about to release, the biggest problem is how to know which projects should be delivered(this is the main problem). Either devs are making notes which project they changed or somebody is going to parse SVN history to check for changes and build those touched projects.

The BIG question is how to do it properly without need to investigate what was changed and release only subset of projects?

We have some ideas
- create SVN branch which will contain only those projects that will be delivered, but how to apply this after transition to GIT?(unable to branch just some files)
- some tables to note changes are problematic, somebody can forget to note his changes there
- we can manage the subproject versions in some parent pom, but still the release will build all project, I don't know how to limit it some projects only

NOTE: we don't want to release unchanged projects

Comment: Can you narrow down your question?  You are asking about Maven, release strategies, CVS, and Git, all in one question.

Comment: It is mainly about the subject, how to release changing subset of projects. How to specify which projects to build, so we can do it "automatically"

Comment: Are you sure that you use CVS?

Comment: Sleepy today sorry it is SVN I don't understand how I got so confused

Comment: What is your intention with your *release*? I often use this word for declaring a bundle of something to be able to get deployed on a productive system - that for, also every dependency that didn't change has to be in the bundle!

Comment: At least the .war files are independent and only some, that have been changed will be deployed. Sometimes the shared libraries are not changed so there is no need to update version. One more caveat, we are using shared library folder for all .wars, .ejbs, which makes the hell more hellish. We think that first step is to get rid of this shared libraries and put the dependencies directly to each .war file.

Comment: Interesting read [here](https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Releasing+modules+of+a+multi-module+project+with+independent+version+numbers)